# Location of UK Town to Postal Sector database or .csv

Tags: united-kingdom, postal-code

I've been searching all over, but cannot find a database/CSV for matching a UK Town to postal sectors.

Example:

```
Hampton Hill” is postcode sector” TW12 1
```

Comment: I think this is a question that would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Ordnance Survey [Code Point Open](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html#CODEPO). It has administrative district code and administrative ward code attributes you can join to [ons codes](https://ons.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ed0cdba2b7141bc8ae8821d107e1207) to get the relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

Ordnance Survey [Open Names](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html) (open data) gives you **postcode** and **populated place**, where populated place is a city, town, village, or some other place where people live.

For example:

```
SW1A 1AA -> City of Westminster
RG4 7LR  -> Caversham
OX1 1AA  -> Oxford
```